# how to query the azure hdinsight hadoop cluster yarn timeline server

Tags: azure, hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

How can I query timeline server in Azure HDInsight Hadoop cluster for getting job metrics?

connecting to the azure cluster:

`curl -u admin -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME"`

connecting to timeline server: `GET /ws/v1/timeline/`

I need a query joining these two to get job metrics of Azure HDInsight Hadoop cluster. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Querying Yarn timeline server:**
   sshuser@clustername:~$ curl -u admin -G 
   https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net/ws/v1/timeline/
2. **For all the running jobs:**
   sshuser@clustername:~$ yarn application –list
3. **For all the job states:**
   sshuser@clustername:~$ yarn application –list -appStates ALL
4. **For all the finished jobs:**
   sshuser@clustername:~$ yarn application –list -appStates FINISHED
5. **Get the Application-Id from the above result:**
   sshuser@clustername:~$ curl -u admin -G 
   https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net/ws/v1/applicationhistory/apps/appID